# Dispatching CustomEvent with dot in name do not trigger jQuery.on() event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, jquery-events, custom-events

I've used jQuery version 2.2.4 and tried to capture event - no luck. Is there any way to fix issue?

This code works:

```
window.addEventListener('test.namespace', e => console.log('CustomEvent with namespace captured by vanilla'));
```

This does not work:

```
$(window).on('test.namespace', e => console.log('CustomEvent with namespace captured by jQuery'));

const event = new CustomEvent('test.namespace', {
  bubbles: true,
  detail: 123
});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

http://jsbin.com/tecupavuji/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "normal" DOM event system doesn't have a concept of namespaces. `window.addEventListener('test.namespace', ...)` will literally be listening for an event with the name `test.namespace`, which is what you are creating with `new CustomEvent('test.namespace', ...)`.

[Event namespaces](https://api.jquery.com/on/) is a concept in jQuery:

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify removing or triggering the event. For example, `"click.myPlugin.simple"` defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be removed with `.off("click.myPlugin")` or `.off("click.simple")` without disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements.

What's important here is that **the namespace is not part of the event name**. That's why `new CustomEvent('test.namespace', ...)` doesn't work, but `new CustomEvent('test', ...)` would.

If you want to trigger an event for a specific namespace, you have to use jQuery for that:

```
$(window).trigger('test.namespace', {detail: 123});
```

```js
$(window).on('test.namespace', e => console.log('CustomEvent with namespace captured by jQuery'));

$(window).trigger('test.namespace', {detail: 123});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer doesn't really address the problem of how to register a handler for a custom event which comes from a third-party (non-jQuery) library and which has a dot in the event name.  Say the event is `foo.bar`.

The short answer is that jQuery doesn't have a way to install a handler for such an event.

`$(window).on( 'foo.bar' )` will instead install a handler for the event `foo`.

There doesn't seem to be any way to escape the dot in the name or otherwise coerce jQuery into installing a handler for an event named `foo.bar`.

Comment: No wonder I made ChatGPT go in circles, then.